# Display time difference (6 hours ago) in a Soliloquy caption

Tags: plugin-development, date

Thanks for viewing. I am using a soliloquy plugin addon to display post date in slide captions. I want to change the post date to human difference or 'hours ago' format. I'm converting `get_the_date` using the following in functions file

```
// Relative date & time
function wpse_relative_date() {
  return human_time_diff( get_the_time('U'), current_time( 'timestamp' ) ) . ' ago';
}
add_filter( 'get_the_date', 'wpse_relative_date' );
```

and the plugin is

```
function sol_soliloquy_fc_date_terms( $content, $post, $data ) {

    // Start Config
    $sliderSlugs = array(
        'your-slider-slug-name',
    );

    // Check slider ID is the one we want to amend
    if ( ! in_array( $data['config']['slug'], $sliderSlugs ) ) {
        return $content;
    }

    // Build date and taxonomy terms content
    $additional_content =       

    '<div class="soliloquy-fc-date">'
        . __( '', 'soliloquy-featured-content-date-terms' ) . get_the_date( 'dS F Y', $post->ID ) . ' 
    </div>';


    // Return content
    return $content . $additional_content;

}
add_filter( 'soliloquy_fc_caption', 'sol_soliloquy_fc_date_terms', 1, 3 );
```

This outputs the amount of days the first post was created and all others are the same so I am guessing it's not returning each posts time because it's outside the loop. I'm a php newbie and I am guessing it's something to do with not being able to use the `$post->ID` inside the `get_the_date`.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your filter function you should pass post ID to `get_the_time()` function, otherwise you will get the date from current post.

```
function wpse_relative_date( $date, $format, $post ) {
   return human_time_diff( get_the_time('U', $post), current_time( 'timestamp' ) ) . ' ago';
}
add_filter( 'get_the_date', 'wpse_relative_date', 15, 3 );
```

---

References:

- [get_the_time()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_time) function
- [get_the_date](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/get_the_date) filter

Comment: @Visible Add an additional argument `$post` to `get_the_time()` used in your `wpse_relative_date()` function.

Comment: That did it! Thank you!